# python: unrecognized arguments & command not found

Tags: python, argparse

I just wrote the following `Python` file, which is called `mypython.py`. The relevant code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Parameter Processing')

    parser.add_argument('--dataset', type=str, default='CIFAR10', help='dataset')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    main(args)
```

And I have a file whose name is "run.sh", which contains:

```
python mypython.py \
--dataset=CIFAR100
```

When I run the command `bash run.sh`
I get the next error:

```
usage: mypython.py [-h] [--dataset DATASET]
mypython.py: error: unrecognized arguments: 
run.sh: line 2: --dataset=CIFAR100: command not found
```

So what's the problem? How can I solve it?

`--dataset CIFAR100` doesn't work too.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an invisible NBSP (non-breaking space) right after the backslash in your `run.sh`. Delete this invalid character, or just recreate the file and it should run fine.
It is usually inserted when you type `AltGr+\`, which happens very often around backslashes.
I reproduced your exact problem in my own editor, but it displayed the character to me (PyCharm).

Comment: Oh it's the careless problem...  It's solved! Thanks!

Comment: @JerryHu Consider marking the answer as accepted then :)